# Loading data into an array from a text file

Tags: java, arrays, split

I'm really struggling with a piece of work, I need to load data from a text file into an array, I have managed to load the data into java and print it, but now the data needs to be split and passed to another class. I tried using `.split(" ")` but the data doesn't share a common amount of white space so I end up with a huge array half of which is filled with entries that have 2 lots of data or just a white space. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Reader {

    int i= 0;
    int k=0;
    static String test;

    public static void main(String[] Args){ 

    String file ="1RainfallSample.txt";        

    //reading   
    try{
        InputStream ips=new FileInputStream(file); 
        InputStreamReader ipsr=new InputStreamReader(ips);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(ipsr);
        String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
        test+=line+"\n";
        }
        br.close(); 

    }       
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    } 

    // split(String Delimiter)
    String[] dataArray=test.split("\\s");
    System.out.println("Array :"+dataArray.length);
    for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("array"+i+"  :"+dataArray[i]);
    } 

    }
}
```

And below is a small example of the data because I don't think I explained it very well.

```
4   6.10   1.80   1.00  26.10   9.60   0.00   0.00   0.00 

0.00   0.00   3.10   0.30   0.20   0.40  0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   

0.00   2.50   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00 -99.992011
```

I feel like I'm approaching it all the wrong way, I'm not a good programmer as you can tell, just a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: first change  test+=line+"  " cause u want space for delimeter .and  u can use regex inside split . for spaces .split("\s+") it will use spaces as split

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
String[] dataArray = test.split("\\s+");
```

to get rid of extra white spaces.

Comment: Holy crap you guys answer questions fast!

Comment: :) Programmers have way too much free time.

Comment: Haha well ty to both of you,  that worked a treat I now have an array of 760 ish  entries instead of 3000 ish, now to work out how to pass this data to the days class :p. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One follow up question i'd ask is how do I then convert the string array into a float, "public float[] (String dataArray[i]);"  I tried putting this in the for loop, but to no avail :\

Comment: @EarlLemongrab: You can declare a `float[] floatArray = new float[dataArray.length]` and use `floatArray[i] = Float.valueOf(dataArray[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively if you want to tidy your data, you could match duplicate spaces and remove them or replace with a single space.

First make sure your text is in a string variable, then:

```
Val = Val.replaceAll(" {2,}", " ");
```

Comment: Thanks @ridoy. I couldn't figure out how to mark code blocks on the mobile app.